# How to use Use Graph QL introspection effectively?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graphql, graphql-js

I have been trying to learn about Graph-QL interpolation recently, however the [official documentation](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) was not helpful enough for me. Is there any way to find all the fields(its subfields), the argument it takes and various other input that could be passed into Graph-QL endpoint ?

Comment: Maybe [this FAQ](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphql-introspection-queries-shoe5xailo) is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out the introspection query that comes with graphql-js [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/bc96406ab44453a120da25a0bd6e2b0237119ddf/src/utilities/introspectionQuery.js). You can use this query to create a complete copy of the schema on the client, minus the resolve functions, which are implementation specific.

PS: It's worth pointing out that due to a limitation of GraphQL the introspection query only goes 6 levels deep for nested arrays, but that should be enough for just about anyone.

Comment: Thanks that helped :D !! I need to send Graph-query queries to some site which is not in my control. Is there any way I could send those queries using explorer like [this](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/explorer/)